# FTP get all files

Tags: php, ftp

I have successfully connected to my FTP using PHP and I can see all the files using: `ftp_nlist`

But, is there an easy way to then download all these files in the current directory?

I can't see to find any examples of how I'd do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another simple solution is ....

List the files in an array and download each file individually.

Something like:

> $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
>
> foreach ($contents as &$value) {
>      $result = ftp_fget($conn_id, $local,&$value, FTP_BINARY);
>   }

You might need to tweak the code a little...

Comment: Just wondering why you are referring to `$value` by reference? ie. `&$value`?

Comment: @w3d is correct. As a matter of fact, including it results in `Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. NanoFTPD is an old project from around 2003. It uses PHP to listen on the FTP port and handles all requests from the client. It is able to do all the functionalities including downloading (all) files to whatever directory you want. Take a look [here](http://nanoftpd.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ftp_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php)

```
$local_file = 'filename.txt';
$server_file = 'filename.txt';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
```