# Downloading and playing multiple wmv files from a remote FTP Server

Tags: php, html, video, ftp

I will do my best to keep this question as simple as possible.

I want to make a video on my site, I haven't yet figured out which media player to use(I might go with the HTML5 one) but I'll find out if I will have my current problem solved. So basically the video has to consist of several wmv files that's being updated on a FTP Server.

I can understand that I should use:

```
ftp_get ( resource $ftp_stream , string $local_file , string $remote_file , int $mode [, int $resumepos = 0 ] )
```

My question is; how would I go around downloading and playing multiple files? And is this possible if I don't know the name of the files, as long as I just need to get all of them?

Any suggestions & answers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Download the files in a seperate directory. Use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to list them all into an array. Use Javascript to play them one after another. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274061/html-5-audio-tag-multiple-files) for an example on how to do that.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328302/ftp-get-all-files) on how to download all files from a FTP directory regardless of their names. It took me about 5 minutes to find all the information you needed. Sometimes all you have to do is research a bit using Google and the SO's search function :)